# Compare two json response and highlight difference in karate

Tags: karate

We have a requirement to compare 2 json responses of same endpoint coming from different environments. We need to compare every attribute (50+) of the response and highlight difference in attributes.
We tried automating the requirement by using match but the issue with match is as soon as it finds failure it stops comparison of further attributes.
Do we have anything in karate which will meet our requirement?